# Are noun+noun and noun's (aphostrope) + noun the same?

Tags: nouns, writing, hyphens

First, please see these examples:

> **Noun+noun:**
>
> - a three-hour journey
> - a ten-pound note
> - a four-week course

> **noun + 's + noun:**
>
> - I've got **a week's holiday** starting on Monday.
> - Julia has got **three weeks' holiday**.
> - I live near the station and it's only **ten-minutes' walk**.

Are those the same way to say something? I mean, for the first example, can I write **a three-hour journey** as **three hours' journey**?

Likewise, can I write **three weeks' holiday** as **three-week holiday**? Etc. And please, I hope you'll mention about the rule of using a hyphen sign **(-)**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both **three weeks' holiday** and **a three-week holiday** are possible. The hyphenated form acts like an adjective. "I live ten minutes' walk from the station" does not need a hyphen.

However, *three hours' journey* doesn't quite seem idiomatic to me, though I can't explain why.

See [this](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/10/genitive.html)

Comment: I’ve seen “X hours’ Y” (AmE, primarily Northeast and West Coast). Not common, but then this form isn’t common in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20three-hour%20journey%2C%20a%20three%20hours%27%20journey&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20three%20-%20hour%20journey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20three%20hours%20%27%20journey%3B%2Cc0) shows that both ***a three-hour journey*** and ***a three hours' journey*** are correct, but the latter is definitely less common.

This other [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20week%27s%20holiday%2C%20a%20week%20holiday%2C%20one%20week%20holiday&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20week%20%27s%20holiday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20week%20holiday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20week%20holiday%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20week%20%27s%20holiday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20week%20holiday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20week%20holiday%3B%2Cc0) shows what I intuitively thought that if the unit of the measure we use to modify a noun is ONE, you must use ***'s***

> ***a week's holiday*** (not a week holiday)

Also, we say

> ***a ten-pound note*** (not a ten pounds' note) ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ten-pound%20note%2Cten%20pounds%27%20note&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cten%20-%20pound%20note%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cten%20-%20pound%20note%3B%2Cc0))